# Css overflow image hidden equally in both margins

Tags: html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I'm making a website with bootstrap's Carousel.
I wish that when the window size is reduced the image in carousel **cut equally** both left and right margin. How can I do it?
I've used overflow: hidden in the css to cut the image but but is **reduced only in the right margin**!
Sorry for my bad English, hope to find a solution with you.

Comment: Could you please add the code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the image position is centered then when the image is resized, the image will be 'cut' from both sides.

```
img{
  background-position:center;
}
```